# How to fetch muliple select query by store procedure in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I created a store procedure for selecting use image detail....
I want to fetch user related all images from table....to delete them from my uploads folder.....

For selecting image name I created store procedure in mysql which is below:

```
DELIMITER //

 CREATE PROCEDURE delphoto (IN  id  INT)
     BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE fld_userId = id;
       SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE tbl_spouse = id;
       SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE tbl_daughter = id;
       SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE tbl_son = id;

     END//
```

---

The problem is this: how do I fetch all the result from this query in php by pdo?
when I run this store procedure it only returned the first column
 result of this query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE fld_userId = id;
```

.....
rest is not executing ....
How do I fetch multiple query result from store procedure by pdo php?

Comment: You have to combine that in a single result query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE 
fld_userId = id OR tbl_spouse = id OR tbl_daughter = id OR tbl_son = id;
```

no procedures re1uired